# AJAX error handling/checking

Tags: ajax

I'm using a method that I've used in another site.  I don't know why, but AJAX keeps going to error posting "Arraynull".  I understand this means "array is null", but when I run the mysql statement, I get plenty of results.

the data is built from a MVC component in Joomla, query, as I'm testing it, is super simple.

```
function loadOpenhouse() {
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "
        SELECT *
            FROM ".$db->nameQuote('#__mls').";";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $openhouse = $db->loadRowList();
    echo $openhouse;
}
```

Then the view just puts it into JSON and echos it.

```
function display($tpl = null) {
        $model = $this->getModel();
        $array = $model->loadOpenhouse();
        echo json_encode($array);
}
```

Again, simple AJAX call...

```
function runQuery(){

var url = 'index.php?option=com_singleprop&view=raw&format=raw';

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){ 
        $('#prop_details').append(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {  
            alert(jqXHR.responseText); 
    }
});

};
```

But in the alert I keep getting "Arraynull".  The array should not be null. When I run the query in CMD, I get values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of echoing the query result return it.

```
return $openhouse;
```

Comment: Any reason the page would keep crashing after this change?

Comment: @tPlummer have no idea, what kind of crash?

Comment: It was because, while troubleshooting, I was trying to load EVERY entry in the DB, which is pretty stinkin' big. :)